# Flex navigateToURL method not working

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I used navigateToURL method to navigate to aspx web page. I used url request as Post method but when i check this in the webpage the http method turned to Get method. Any one please help. I loaded the Flex page into the windows application

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to a security restruction. If you are executing navigateToURL from an AIR app, the POST will be treated as a GET. Please see the security notes at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL()

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i'm not using an AIR app. I'm loading Flex .swf in Windows application using ShockwaveFlashObjects.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your URLRequest object has URLVariables attached to it (even if the the variables are empty). If you have no data then the player will convert the POST to GET. This is normal, expected behavior.

http://mate.asfusion.com/forums/topic.php?id=70